# How to put a dynamic text on top of an image for different email providers ? (Responsive Email)

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email, responsive

I am currently working on an email template that has to be compatible with the major email providers.

According with the client I supposed to create a salutation paragraph or header on top of an image so i tried this solution which is working fine on browser but definitely not on the emails (tested on Outlook, hotmail, gmail and yahoo) and none of these read the property position: absolute(i think not sure).

The template has also to be responsive so if i resize the the screen the text should adjust regarding the width of the screen.
Because of the multiple issues on email i had to create 2 tables one inside the other in order to create a border around the image and then the second table inside to display the image itself.

The text should be inside the pink roadsign and it's Hi Margaret, which will be then dynamic.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
      <meta charset="UTF-8">

<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background: #dff1f6 !important;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .preheader {
        display: none !important;
        visibility: hidden !important;
        opacity: 0 !important;
        color: transparent !important;
        height: 0 !important;
        width: 0 !important;
    }

    @media (max-width: 376px) {
        .anglianlogo {
            max-width: 250px !important;
        }

        .anglianwellcome {
            font-size: 11px !important;
        }

        .awvideopreview {
            height: 150px;
        }

        .mobileresize {
            width: 90% !important;
            font-size: 9px;
        }
    }
</style>
```

```
<div style="background: #dff1f6;">

    <!--Container-->

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;width:100%;">
        <tr><td colspan="3" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;font-size:20px;height:20px;" height="20">&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="padding:0px;margin:0px;" width="600">

                <!--Main Table-->

                <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="max-width: 600px; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; background: white;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>


                            <!--Video-->


                            <table width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="padding-bottom: 30px; padding-left:10%; padding-right:10%; width:100%;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="text-align:center; margin: 0 auto;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0; border: 10px solid #72b8d1;">
                                                    <a style="margin: 0 auto; display: block;">
                                                        <!--href="{{ CustomerData.vidUrl }}"-->
                                                        <img class="awvideopreview" src="https://preview.ibb.co/gKOzsv/Videopreview.gif" width="450" border="0" align="center" style="width:100%;">
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>


                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                      <!--End Table-->

                 </td>
                 <td style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">&nbsp;</td>
             </tr>
                <tr><td colspan="3" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;font-size:20px;height:20px;" height="20">&nbsp;</td></tr>
         </table>

       <!--End Container-->
    </div>

     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you have inside your CSS classes? Please put your code in jsfiddle so I can test it on e-mail.
HTML for e-mails takes a different approach than normaly. A lot of tables and inline styling and compatibility issues.

Checkout this link. It can help find you some problems. (but for now show us the fiddle)

https://www.htmlemailcheck.com/

Comment: hi mate I was able to copy some of the code and put it here so now is updated. thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 0):

You'll be best off using a background image if you need to overlay copy

https://backgrounds.cm/ is the best tool for that. Just set the dimensions, add your image link, this will generate the VML code for you and then any overlayed content is placed within the `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what i use on my emails. The VML part takes care of Outlooks and the background defined in td's takes care of other email clients. I use heights on td to keep the image at a specific height (optional) and with the class you can control the height using media queries.

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="background: url([IMAGE PATH]); background-image: url([IMAGE PATH]); background-color:#[BACKGROUND COLOR];" height="[HEIGHT]" class="[YOUR CLASS]">
  
     <!--[if gte mso 9]>
   <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:[WIDTH]px;height:[HEIGHT]px;">
   <v:fill type="frame" src="[IMAGE PATH]" color="#[BACKGROUND COLOR]" />
   <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]--> 

  [HTML CONTENT HERE]

  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
   </v:textbox>
   </v:rect>
  <![endif]-->
   
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Let me know if this is what you were after.